# Maven Generating Archetype getting package variable as directory format

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, archetypes

I'm looking to make an archetype and I'm having difficulty making the created pom.xml have the values I need it to.

I have:

```
<properties>
    <domain-objects-location> ${groupId}/domain </domain-objects-location>
    ...
</properties>
```

in my pom.xml template, and I get "com.mycompany.app" where groupID is.

However I want "com/mycompany/app" to be there.

Any suggestions on how to get that? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

As I linked below, there is a special property for doing just this.

```
<domain-objects-location>${packageInPathFormat}/domain</domain-objects-location>
```

is what gives me the desired output I was looking for. I'm not sure why this doesn't show up on https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-model/maven.html or somewhere else obvious in the documentation. But it does work.

Comment: So I found a [Useful Guide](http://geekofficedog.blogspot.com/2013/08/creating-maven-archetypes-tutorial.html) that gave me what I was looking for. will update above to reflect the right answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I think I messed up the order of replying to show this answered...

But, http://geekofficedog.blogspot.com/2013/08/creating-maven-archetypes-tutorial.html shows

```
${packageInPathFormat}
```

As the property value I was looking for to get the 'package in path format'. And it works.